# Android error incomparable types: Object and int

Tags: java, android, android-studio, telegram

I am importing a source code, and i've this error in two place of code:

> Error:(86, 60) error: incomparable types: Object and int

```
if (selectedPhotos.containsKey(photoEntry.imageId)) {
  selectedPhotos.remove(photoEntry.imageId);
  v.setChecked(false, true);
  photoEntry.imagePath = null;
  photoEntry.thumbPath = null;
  v.setPhotoEntry(photoEntry, v.getTag() == MediaController.allPhotosAlbumEntry.photos.size() - 1);
                                   // ^-here-^
} else {
  selectedPhotos.put(photoEntry.imageId, photoEntry);
  v.setChecked(true, true);
```

And this one :

```
if (passwordFrameLayout.getTag() != 0) {
//                               ^Here
  t = (Integer) passwordFrameLayout.getTag();
}
```

What changes should I do with these ones?

- I've searched in Stack but I couldn't fix them. I'm a newbie at this, please help.
- I am using Android Studio Last Version by the way!
- I am developing the main [Telegram source](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) with no changes.

And get tag function :

```
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
  public Object getTag() {
    return mTag;
  }
```

is in android-23/android/view/View.java

Comment: What's the type of `getTag()`? It's obviously not an integer.

Comment: @Eran edited and added .

Comment: Well, it doesn't help much to know that it's an Object. What's the actual (specific) type that it returns?

Comment: @Eran the out put type is `FrameLayout passwordFrameLayout`

Comment: Then why are you comparing it to a number? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @Eran i'm wondering too! you know i'm importing Telegram source, And it must be without problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (passwordFrameLayout.getTag() instanceOf Integer && (Integer)passwordFrameLayout.getTag() != 0) {
//         
    t = (Integer) passwordFrameLayout.getTag();
}
```

Should do the trick. `getTag()` returns an Object, you have to

- make sure it's an Integer first
- cast it to Integer

to compare it to another Integer